# Anorm: 'id' not found, available columns: SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Tags: playframework, anorm

I am running a SQL query that works well when copied-and-pasted in H2 or MySQL, but fails in Anorm with a cryptic error message: `'id' not found, available columns: SCOPE_IDENTITY()` :

```
[debug] c.j.b.PreparedStatementHandle -
      INSERT INTO projects (person_id,name,code_name,isControl,toAnalyze)
      VALUES (111,'asdf','asdf',1,1)
[info]   anorm.AnormException: 'id' not found, available columns: SCOPE_IDENTITY(), SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

N.B. There is a column `id` in this table - primary key with auto-increment -, not sure if it is related though.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually due to me querying

```
SQL"...".executeInsert(parser.*)
```

with an ill-defined parser instead of

```
SQL"...".executeInsert()
```

SCOPE_IDENTITY refers to the ids of the inserted rows, and passing a parser to the `executeInsert` method makes it return a list of custom objects (possessing an `id` field, apparently) instead of a list of Ints.